# No scrollbar in GCP cloud shell editor

Tags: google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I do not get a scrollbar in cloud shell editor with which I can move with the mouse up in the terminal window. There is an option in the settings that says show scrollbar but that scrollbar does not work. When I click and drag on it, it selects text.

Also when I use the Terminal in the cloud shell editor there is no scrollbar.

Can I somehow get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

in your cloud Shell, go to the gear icon (settings) >> Terminal Preferences >> Show Scrollbar

once the window was maximized, i was able to upload from the menu or drag and drop directly in the command line interface and scroll upn & down with my mouse without issue.

[image]